# PHP+cURL disable command line progress output

Tags: php, linux, curl

I have a PHP script which connects to a remote server with cURL and download some files. I run it thru the command line,

`php get.php`

Whenever it starts downloading data, I get this output:

```
Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Tim Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100      162k       0        162k            0   0      21732    0       --:--:-- 0:00:07 --:--:-- 36001
```

How do I disable it?

Comment: try curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0);  :: more :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13958303/curl-download-progress-in-php

Comment: `php get.php > /dev/null` not an option?

Comment: If you want you can save the output to a file too php get.php > /home/output.txt and want to append with date in case date;php get.php >> output.txt

Comment: Can you show the script (or the relevant parts)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [manual refering to CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS):

> CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS
>
> TRUE to disable the progress meter for cURL transfers.
>
> Note: PHP automatically sets this option to TRUE, this should only be changed for debugging purposes.

Looks like the progress has been explicitly turned on. Check your code for that option. In any case, if you want to explicitly disable it again, `curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, true)` should do the trick.

Update: If you instead do something like `exec("curl http://example.com")` you should a) think about what you're doing and b) run `curl -s` to disable the progress. PHP's streams have support for http, so you can just use `file_get_contents`, `copy` et al.