# Reload parent page(redirect to another page) after downloading file

Tags: javascript, php, html, download, redirect

I have a script for wav files download:

**down.php**:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['file'])) { 
    $file = $_GET['file'] ;

        if (file_exists($file) && is_readable($file) && preg_match('/\.wav$/',$file))  { 
            $fileName = basename($file);
            header('Content-type: application/wav');  
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$fileName); 

            readfile($file); 
        } 
    } else { 
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); 
    echo "<h1>Error 404: File Not Found: <br /><em>$file</em></h1>"; 
} 
?>
```

so when I click on my hyperlink in **myPage.php**:

```
<a href=<?php echo "down.php?file=full_file_path"?>><?php echo "file_name"?></a>
```

a file gets downloaded!

How can I reload **myPage.php** after **download dialog box** gets closed, that is when a file gets downloaded?

I've tried few things but none of it worked. Like, redirection after readfile(), then I found out that it's impossible to output the header after you have output the file. Calling javascript function on onclick event to reload location. Opening `down.php?file=full_file_path` first and then reloading location. and more ...

Any idea where and how to do it?

Comment: you said you tried a couple of things, but what?

Comment: @RenePot I've uploaded my question

Comment: You might get some ideas from this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19525492/http-file-download-monitoring-download-progress