# Php callbacks for returning percent of process

Tags: php, callback

I have a download method from a library that accepts `callback` function for handling percents of downloaded file.

```
$cb = function ($percent) {
    echo $percent;
};


$info = $MadelineProto->download_to_dir($messageMediaPhoto, 'assets', $cb);
```

But it only echos **100** at the end. How can I get the all percents? How can it be done in a blocking io language?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I implement a callback in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48947/how-do-i-implement-a-callback-in-php)

Comment: Assuming your `download_to_dir` uses curl, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13958303/curl-download-progress-in-php Otherwise, for stream functions like `file_get_contents`, you can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-notification-callback.php

Comment: @AlexBlex Thank you. But until the process is finished, I can't get any percent. I get the whole output once (tested for both linked you provided). How should I send request?

Comment: Well, it was a generic question, if it is possible or not. The answer is yes, it is. If it does not work as expected, it is a debugging kind of a question, which requires an mcve: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Please update the question with reproducible examples of what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in the latest version of MadelineProto.